# Python Package Import Error--Python Doesn't Recognize Package

Tags: python, python-2.7

Recently, in attempting to import a module I'd written, I have been coming across errors that ostensibly should not happen. Here is the idea, I'm writing in my `main.py` file, and my hierarchy looks like this:

```
starsearch/
  main.py
  parser/
    __init__.py
    parse.py
```

the `__ init __.py` file in parser/ is empty, but when I try, in my program, to:

```
import parser
```

it returns an `AttributeError`. This happens when I call the function inside of `parse.py`, called `getstar()`.
or

```
from parser import parse
```

it returns an `ImportError`.

So my Python doesn't recognize that `parse.py` exists? I have done a bit of research, and having an `__ init __.py` file that's empty should do the trick, but I'm stumped.

Comment: The `AttributeError` is because modules in a package aren't attributes of the package -- you have to import them yourself.

Comment: You could always do a brute-force import like:

    import sys
    sys.path.append('parser')
    import parser

Comment: You could be more precise as to what are the error messages returned (and not just their type)?

Comment: @mjgpy3 - super hacky dude. Even for python =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

parser is a name of a build-in module in python.
when you write

```
import parser
```

You import the built-in module. Since that module does not contain the getstar() function or a parse module, you get either AttributeError or ImportError

Try changing the name of the "parser" directory to anything else and it should work. The empty **init**.py file is not needed

Comment: Worked! Thank you, I was beating my head against a wall trying to figure out what was wrong. Would anyone happen to know if there's a list of do's and don't's for naming modules in Python?